# Roots of $x^2-2ax+b=0,~a^2>>b$, stable algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

> Find a stable algorithm for the computation of the roots of the equation $x^2-2ax+b=0$ if $a,~b>0$ and $a^2>>b$.

**Attempt.** The roots are $x_1=a-\sqrt{a^2-b}$ and $x_2=a+\sqrt{a^2-b}$, where we have a cancelation error for the computation of $x_1$, since $a^2-b\cong a^2$. So we compute $\displaystyle x_1=\frac{b}{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}$ (stable algorithm).

**My question**: is it correct to say that $\displaystyle \frac{b}{2a}$ is a "good" approximation for $x_1$? Or should we remain on the algorithm $\displaystyle x_1=\frac{b}{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your approximation does come closer and closer to $x_1$, see for instance [this WA plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1-%28x+%2B+sqrt%28x^2+-+1%29%29%2F%282x%29+for+x+from+3+to+10), of the relative error where $x = \frac ab$. However, whether it's a _good_ approximation depends on your concrete application and fault tolerance. One could, for instance, ask when the approximation error of $\frac b{2a}$ becomes smaller than the cancellation error of $a - \sqrt{a^2 - b}$.

Comment: Actually a floating point issue would be an overflow in the computation of $a^2$. Do you look for such a solution? There are some references if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

- About one part of your question, no purely mathematical answer can be given because $\displaystyle x_1=\frac{b}{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}$ is strictly the same as $a-\sqrt{a^2-b}.$ It is a floating point issue.
- About the other part, yes, $\frac{b}{2a}$ is a good approximation.

This can be attested by applying Taylor expansion :

$$\sqrt{1-x}=1-\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}x^2-\cdots$$

in the following way:

$$x_1=a-\sqrt{a^2-b}=a-a\sqrt{1-\frac{b}{a^2}}=a-a\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{b}{a^2}-\frac{1}{8}\frac{b^2}{a^4}- \cdots\right)$$

Giving :

$$x_1 \ \approx \ \frac{b}{2a}+\frac{b^2}{8a^3}$$

> Thus, the order of the error is approximately: $\frac{b^2}{8a^3}$,
>
> which is very small because $b << a^2.$

Comment: Thank you. Your first bullet refers to the "attempt" or to the "question"?

Comment: I have mixed both, I recognize. The first time I saw the replacement of $a-\sqrt{a^2-b}$ by $\displaystyle \frac{b}{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}$ was in Knuth.

Comment: I don't know who has anonymously downgraded my attempt of explanation... What is wrong with it ?

Comment: All right. I appreciate your honesty. But let me say that 1) I have answered to the question why $b/(2a)$ is a good approximation. 2) I have introduced the term "floating point approximation" that nobody had introduced before.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut What do you mean by "there is a tag" ?

Comment: All right. I didn't have a look at the tags. My fault.

Comment: @JeanMarie: I am also shocked by this downvote, your answer is perfectly valid. The question is not about numerical stability of root computation, which the OP addressed himself, it is about the "goodness" of the approximation.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Thanks

Comment: @Felix Marin I appreciate.

Comment: @JeanMarie ${\large {\bullet\,\,\,\bullet} \atop \smile}$

Comment: ok, mea culpa ;-)

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut Thanks. I appreciate too. Meanwhile, I have found a thorough reference, in a classical book: (http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/linearalgebra/NumericalRecipiesInC/c5-6.pdf) giving "the" good recipe (formula (5,6.5)). An alternative approach: consider roots of a quadratic as eigenvalues like in the interesting paper: "Polynomial Roots From Companion Matrix Eigenvalues" by Alan Edelman and H. Murakami, Math. of Comp. Vol. 64, n°3, April 1995, pp 763-776 (http://math.mit.edu/~edelman/publications/polynomial_roots.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac1{x_1}=\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{b}=\frac ab+\frac ab\sqrt{1-\frac b{a^2}}\approx\frac ab{\left(2-\frac b{2a^2}\right)}$$ so that the relative truncation error is indeed small.

You can safely ignore the correction when $\dfrac b{a^2}<4\text{ ulp}$,  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place). For higher ratios, it will depend on your own accuracy requirements.

Comment: I realize now that I had not covered this aspect in my answer.